# Selenium not showing active session rejected when opening same URL in another tab

Tags: selenium

As per my application, when a user is logged in and then copy pastes the url in a new window or in a new tab of the existing window, it should get get an error message that an active session is already in place. I am trying to automate this scenario through selenium, but when I do that, I am not getting the error message instead it shows the web page correctly.

Below is the code snippet

```
ChromeDriver driver = (ChromeDriver) getWebDriver();
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
SessionId session = driver.getSessionId();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.getSessionId();
driver.get(url);
```

Please note that the sessionID is same when i am switching to new tab.
ChromeDriver version- 2.35
Any Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you getting SessionID same for both tab

Comment: Session ID is of web driver session not the browser session. It should be same.

Comment: Yes it's the session

Comment: Can someone help on the issue. Really stuck with this!!